# c#: winforms: tooltip: how to delay tooltip.Show

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I'm using winforms ToolTip class on a DataGridView (not tooltip of datagridview since I need custom formatting.)

And I call toolTip.Show() in DataGridView's CellMouseEnter event.

toolTip.Show() shows the the tooltip immediately and InitialDelay property is not working since I called toolTip.Show().

Is there another way to delay toolTip.Show() just like regular initaldelay.

Comment: It is not supposed to work.  Consider setting the cell's ToolTipText property instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, it should work by setting ShowCellToolTips  property from DataGridView to false, after that, ToolTip component can be used as for other controls ;)

Answer (score 1):

ToolTip *Show* method shows right away the tooltip text, if you want a delay you have to use *SetToolTip* instead, being 5000 milliseconds the maximun:

```
toolTip.InitialDelay = 5000;
toolTip.SetToolTip(dataGridView1, "Max InitialDelay is 5000 milliseconds");
```

Note: for the above to work properly, remember you first have to disable DataGridView builtin tooltip :

```
dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;
```

**EDIT**: To show tool tip for each row (and cell). 
Note the use of *CellMouseEnter* and *CellMouseLeave* events

```
private ToolTip toolTip;

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
    var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (cell.Value != null){
        toolTip = new ToolTip();
        toolTip.InitialDelay = 3000;
        dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;
        toolTip.SetToolTip(dataGridView1, cell.Value.ToString());
    }    
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (toolTip != null)
         toolTip.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I changed my toolTip.Show to toolTip.SetTooltip. InitialDelay is working smooth with other controls but for datagridview its a little complicated. It works for the first time when mouse enter DataGirdViewCell since the paremeter Control for SetTooltip is DataGridView. but when  I move the mouse to another cell tooltip immediately shows for the new cell (actually I think that it doesnt disapears at all since SetTooltip param is still DataGridView not a cell). ReshowDelay also useless here becuase it sets the reshow delay only when pointer moves from one control to another( not in same control)

Comment: Do you want to show tooltip for each cell? I meant, different text for different cells?

Comment: Simple solution for design time is: [MSDN instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984298(v=vs.71).aspx) that is valid for all versions of VS including VS2015

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem; I created a new instance of ToolTip in DataGridView CellMouseEnter event and disposed it in CellMouseLeave event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        // 
        // create and initilize toolTip1
        // 
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
        this.toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.toolTip1.UseAnimation = false;
        this.toolTip1.UseFading = false;
        this.toolTip1.Draw += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.toolTip1_Draw);
        this.toolTip1.Popup += new System.Windows.Forms.PopupEventHandler(this.toolTip1_Popup);

        toolTip1.SetToolTip((DataGridView)sender, e.RowIndex.ToString() + " : " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        toolTip1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I m not sure if it is a good practice. I think it is not good for performance. because I can see it when scrolling datagridview up and down with mouse wheel, some rows seem like frozen for a moment until wheel stops.

if there is a better solution please advice.